# How to put the value of an entry into a variable in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to get the value of an entry in tkinter!

when I print the value directly ( for example  print(e2.get() ) it works well, but when I put this into a variable and then print it ( for example  x = e2.get() print(x) ) it's not working!

here is the code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def show_entry_fields():
    print("First Name: %s\n Last Name: %s" % (x, e2.get()))

master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, 
         text="First Name").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master, 
         text="Last Name").grid(row=1)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

x = e1.get()

tk.Button(master, 
          text='Quit', 
          command=master.quit).grid(row=3, 
                                    column=0, 
                                    sticky=tk.W, 
                                    pady=4)
tk.Button(master, 
          text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, 
                                                       column=1, 
                                                       sticky=tk.W, 
                                                       pady=4)

tk.mainloop()
```

I need to put the entry value in a variable, how can I do it?

Comment: which line is in error ? `x = e1.get()` ?

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? Does it get the wrong value?

Comment: Are you aware that when you do `x=e1.get()`, it gets the value at that moment in time? `x` won't be updated later if the value in `e1` changes.

Comment: there is no error, just in line `print("First Name: %s\n Last Name: %s" % (x, e2.get()))` `e2.get()` going to print but x do not! Instead of x, an empty content is printed! @HippolyteBRINGER @BryanOakley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple if you understand :

When the code pass by `x = e1.get()`, `e1` equals just `""`.

After your write in `e1` and call the def `show_entry_fields` when you click in the button.

But `x` is always equals to `""`.
And `e1.get()` get the text in the `e1`.

So it's why `print(x)` equals `""` because you pass by the line `x = e1.get()` just one time !